# Format the numbers in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query with some case statements within it and one of them determines how much an account is to be paid and right now everything is fine but I was hoping to do formatting for the results, how it is displayed in SQL. I am using SQL Server Management Studio (SQL Server 2016).

I am trying to use `'$' + Format(col_name, '#,###')` to display results as currency but no decimals. The picture shows you what I currently have after I run my query.

When I tried to incorporate the above format, I get `Msg 402 Error The data types nvarchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator.`

Not sure how to modify my codes.

```
CASE    
    WHEN (prior.amountpaid - prior.amountOwed) < 0 THEN p.amountpaid
    ELSE
         prior.amountpaid - prior.amountOwed + p.amountpaid
         END AS 'Amount Paid',
```

[image]

Comment: The error couldn't be more clear. The reason that is happening is because FORMAT returns character data and you are trying to math on it. Leave the formatting to the front end, not in your query.

Comment: If you are storing `decimal` data in an `nvarchar` field, then you would need to convert that before subtracting.  You can use `convert` or `cast` for that, or if the data might not be numeric, you could use `try_convert` for example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the FORMAT function around the entire CASE expression, instead of doing it on the individual columns.

Answer (score 2):

Format the Result not each column

```
CASE    
WHEN (prior.amountpaid - prior.amountOwed) < 0 THEN '$' + Format(p.amountpaid, '#,###')
ELSE
     '$' + Format((prior.amountpaid - prior.amountOwed + p.amountpaid), '#,###')
     END AS 'Amount Paid'
```

But if you can leave the formatting to the Front End not the database call, you never know what math you may want to perform in the Business logic and working with strings is a pain.